# Is it acceptable to bring trivial requests to God?

Tags: tefilla

I think that seeking divine assistance should be reserved for significant concerns such as health or crucial life decisions, and that matters of lesser importance such as minor daily inconveniences, like finding a parking space or having good weather may not warrant seeking God's intervention but some of my friends have suggested that there is no limit to what we can request from God.

Is it acceptable to bring trivial requests to God?

Comment: The question presumes that Hashem agrees withour evaluation of what is significant and what is minor. This is logical for our relationship with a King, but have you got any reason to presume it is the same for Hashem?

Comment: I was once listening to a SEED tape, the speaker pointed out that the difference between Jewish prayer and non-Jewish prayer is that Jews pray for trivial things. For example, he said he lost the screw for his glasses arm on the carpet and prayed he should find it.

Comment: From God's perspective, aren't they all trivial?

Comment: From memory, I think that Rabbi Shalom Arush encourages praying for everything including the most insignificant details in Garden of Emunah.  At the end of the day, God is infinitely powerful, has infinite patience and isn't going to get annoyed with our constant requests, and they do serve to maintain a connection to Him and make us appreciate that every little thing comes from Him.

Comment: You can ask God whatever you want. Doesn't mean that God will grant your request though.